# How to avoid CORS error when using Puppeteer inside Firebase Callable Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I am attempting to take a screenshot of a web page using puppeteer inside a callable firebase cloud function.  I keep getting a CORS error and the other solutions listed as answers do not seem to solve my problem.

Per another question's answer, I have given allUsers the cloud function invoker role.

Is there anything obvious in my code that would cause the CORS issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

exports.takePic = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {
    return cors(req, res, async () => {
        const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
        const url = data.url
        (async () => {
          const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            args: [
              '--disable-web-security',
              '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins',
              '--disable-site-isolation-trials'
            ],
            headless: false,
          });
          const page = await browser.newPage();
          await page.goto(url);
          await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });
        
          await browser.close();
        })();
    })
});
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Where are you getting the error? When calling the function, or when pupeteer calls the external page?